# How to use DataGridColumnHeader's style for GridViewColumnHeader in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

The style for DataGridColumnHeader is defined in toolkit I use and can change in every version. Can I tell for GridViewColumnHeader to use style defined for DataGridColumnHeader? If so, how?

Comment: You cannot use the same style as the controls are different. Just define the same style again inside your toolkit and then change the TargetType to GridViewColumnHeader, give a different key to the style and use it.

Comment: thanks! that's what i thought. the problem with your suggestion is that I don't see the style definition for DataGridColumnHeader.

Answer (score 4):

The setters in WPF styles are checked during compile time; CSS styles are applied dynamically.

You can set the target type to base classes like 'control'.

```
<Style x:Key="Highlight" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

And now you can use this style on all classes which are a sub class from 'control':

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource Highlight}" Content="Test"/>
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource Highlight}" Text="Test"/>
```

But i don't think that this is possible on DataGridColumnHeader and GridViewColumnHeader, because their controls are basically different.

Comment: thanks! I was hoping the common parts would be used.

Comment: actually you can make style with target GridViewColumnHeader that is based on styöe targeting DataGridColumnHeader. there's no exception or anything. it just seems that it does not work. I tried same with other control types and it resulted in exception.